Proof of Theorem related to Measure Valued Pólya Process
I'm trying to prove the following, but I don't know if what I did is actually enough, although it does not seem the case to prove more. These concepts come from this document. N.B. In the document, it is given a hint to use "De Finetti's Theorem", but actually I was told that "new" and easier (shorter) methods are present in the literature (I actually could not find anything useful on the net..)

Let $E$ be a Polish space, and let $\mathcal{M}_f(E)$ denote the space of finite measures on $E$. A Measure-Valued Pólya Process (MVPP) $(m_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is defined as follows:
Let $m_0 \in \mathcal{M}_f(E)$, and for $n \geq 0$, given $m_n$, define:
$$
m_{n+1} = m_n + R^{(n+1)}_{Y(n+1)},
$$
where $Y(n+1)$ is a random variable distributed according to $m_n / m_n(E)$,
$R^{(n+1)}_{Y(n+1)}$ is an independent copy of $R^{(1)}_{Y(n+1)}$, a replacement kernel defined as a random kernel $R^{(1)}: E \to \mathcal{M}_f(E)$.

For this theorem, the replacement kernel is specified as $R^{(1)}_x = \delta_x$, i.e., the identity kernel.

Let $\mu \in \mathcal{M}_f(E)$ be a finite measure, and let $\mu^*$ be a Ferguson($\mu$) distributed random probability measure on $E$. Suppose $(X(i))_{i \geq 1}$ are i.i.d. random variables distributed according to $\mu^*$, and define:
$$
m_n = \mu + \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X(i)} \quad \text{for } n \geq 0.
$$
Then, the sequence $(m_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is an MVPP with initial composition $\mu$ and replacement kernel $\mathrm{Id}$.

My Attempt at the Proof:
From the theorem, the initial measure is given by $m_0 = \mu$. This matches the definition of the MVPP, where the process starts with an initial finite measure.
The update rule for the MVPP is:
$$
m_{n+1} = m_n + R^{(n+1)}_{Y(n+1)},
$$
where $Y(n+1)$ is a random variable with distribution $m_n / m_n(E)$, and $R^{(n+1)}_{Y(n+1)} = \delta_{Y(n+1)}$ (since the replacement kernel is the identity kernel).
Given $m_n = \mu + \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X(i)}$, the sampling distribution of $Y(n+1)$ becomes:
$$
\frac{m_n}{m_n(E)} = \frac{\mu}{\mu(E) + n} + \frac{1}{\mu(E) + n} \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X(i)}.
$$
This matches the predictive distribution of the Ferguson process. Thus, $Y(n+1)$ is distributed according to $\mu^*$.
The update rule $m_{n+1} = m_n + \delta_{Y(n+1)}$ matches the construction of $m_n$ in the theorem:
$$
m_{n+1} = \mu + \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \delta_{X(i)},
$$
where $X(n+1)$ is distributed as $Y(n+1)$.
By definition of the MVPP, $R^{(n+1)}_{Y(n+1)} = \delta_{Y(n+1)}$ is independent of the past, given $Y(n+1)$. In the theorem's construction: the $X(i)$'s are i.i.d. given $\mu^*$, ensuring that the updates are independent.
Thus, $(m_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is an MVPP with initial composition $\mu$ and replacement kernel $\mathrm{Id}$.

Does the upvote mean that it is a nice proof or just highlights a good question?
